# What is meant by the phrase "first tag wiki edit"?

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-wiki

I find this badge tip extremely confusing: tag editor. What is meant by the text provided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get it the first time you edit a tag wiki.

A tag wiki provides extended information about a tag, which can help to set the boundaries of how it's used. Here's the [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/info) as an example.

Comment: This might be a candidate for rewriting the badge helper text.

Comment: @Tray It seems to make perfect sense to me..

Comment: I could imagine it sounds a bit like "correct horse battery staple" if you aren't familiar with our tagging system. I'm not sure how much more useful it could be while still remaining brief though.